# Mostrar por pantalla elementos de un Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

me encuentro atascado en este punto:

Quiero mostrar por pantalla los objetos de la clase Room almacenados dentro del Arraylist listaHabitaciones perteneciente a la clase HotelRio.

Dentro de la función principal de la clase HotelRio he creado un Arraylist en el que quiero almacenar objetos de la clase Room. Mi intención es tener almacenados los objetos de tipo Room que representarán el conjunto de habitaciones que tiene mi Hotel.

Así que creo los objetos tipo Room y los almaceno en el Arraylist con el metodo .add(), indicando dentro de los parámetros el ínidice y el nombre del objeto.

Al mostrar por pantalla los objetos situados dentro del
Arraylist siempre me da como resultado el último objeto introducido.

Quiero que me muestre cada uno de ellos.

```
public class Room {

private static int roomNumber;
private static String tipoHab;
private static String tipoAseo;

public Room(int roomNumber, String tipoHab, String tipoAseo)
{
    this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
    this.tipoHab = tipoHab;
    this.tipoAseo = tipoAseo;

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    
    return ("Numero de habitación es: "+roomNumber + "\n Tipo habitación: " +tipoHab + "\nTipo Aseo: " +tipoAseo);
}
    
    
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HotelRio{


    public HotelRio()

    {


    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    ArrayList <Room> listaHabitaciones = new ArrayList<>();

    Room room101 = new Room(101, "ADAPTADA", "DUCHA");
    Room room102 = new Room(102, "TRIPLE", "DUCHA");
    Room room103 = new Room(103, "DOBLE", "BAÑO");

    listaHabitaciones.add(0, room101);;
    listaHabitaciones.add(1, room102);
    listaHabitaciones.add(2, room103);

    System.out.println(room101.toString());
    System.out.println(room102.toString());
    System.out.println(room103.toString());

    }
  
  
}
```

```
OUTPUT:

Numero de habitación es: 103
Tipo habitación: DOBLE
Tipo Aseo: BAÑO

Numero de habitación es: 103
Tipo habitación: DOBLE
Tipo Aseo: BAÑO

Numero de habitación es: 103
Tipo habitación: DOBLE
Tipo Aseo: BAÑO
```

Comment: te devuelve los dato del ultimo objeto creado por que as declarado las variables de la clase `Room` como `static` ,solo déjalas como `private` ,lo otro es que para mostrar los  datos solo necesitas imprimir la lista donde agregaste los objetos  `listaHabitaciones.forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo. Me imprime la misma habitación 3 veces. El problema reside en que me imprime el último objeto introducido en el ArrayList

Comment: yeah!! Muchas gracias!! No había caído en esto!

Answer (score 0):

Hay diferentes formas de mostrar los elementos de un ArrayList. Te pongo algunas. Te dejo un enlace de dónde he sacado la información, más a bajo.

**Bucle for:**

```java
for(int i = 0; i < listaHabitaciones.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(listaHabitaciones.get(i));
}
```

**Método foreach:**

```java
modelList.forEach(new Consumer<Room>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Room room) {
        System.out.println(room);
    }
});
```

**Método .toString():**

```java
System.out.println(listaHabitaciones.toString())
```

Origen de la información: https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/java/print-arraylist-java/

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.